# Como acessar a versão de um arquivo.exe com PHP?

Tags: php

Preciso acessar a propriedade chamada "versão" no meu arquivo, e sei que isso não é possível em Javascript, mas não sei qual linguagem usar, ou o que fazer para chegar a isso. Pensei em usar PHP, mas não possuo muito conhecimento nesta área, poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Seu servidor é windows ou linux?

Comment: É o oferecido pela hostGator

Comment: Apenas eCHEF_x64.exe   não tem arquivo js

Answer (score 2):

> **AVISO:** Todos os códigos nesta resposta foram escritos por terceiros e não foram testados por mim. Cuidado ao utilizá-los.

No Stack Overflow em inglês tem [uma pergunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2029409), e o usuário Toni postou lá o seguinte código:

```
<?php
function GetFileVersion($FileName) {

    $handle=fopen($FileName,'rb');
    if (!$handle) return FALSE;
    $Header=fread ($handle,64);
    if (substr($Header,0,2)!='MZ') return FALSE;
    $PEOffset=unpack("V",substr($Header,60,4));
    if ($PEOffset[1]<64) return FALSE;
    fseek($handle,$PEOffset[1],SEEK_SET);
    $Header=fread ($handle,24);
    if (substr($Header,0,2)!='PE') return FALSE;
    $Machine=unpack("v",substr($Header,4,2));
    if ($Machine[1]!=332) return FALSE;
    $NoSections=unpack("v",substr($Header,6,2));
    $OptHdrSize=unpack("v",substr($Header,20,2));
    fseek($handle,$OptHdrSize[1],SEEK_CUR);
    $ResFound=FALSE;
    for ($x=0;$x<$NoSections[1];$x++) {      //$x fixed here
        $SecHdr=fread($handle,40);
        if (substr($SecHdr,0,5)=='.rsrc') {         //resource section
            $ResFound=TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$ResFound) return FALSE;
    $InfoVirt=unpack("V",substr($SecHdr,12,4));
    $InfoSize=unpack("V",substr($SecHdr,16,4));
    $InfoOff=unpack("V",substr($SecHdr,20,4));
    fseek($handle,$InfoOff[1],SEEK_SET);
    $Info=fread($handle,$InfoSize[1]);
    $NumDirs=unpack("v",substr($Info,14,2));
    $InfoFound=FALSE;
    for ($x=0;$x<$NumDirs[1];$x++) {
        $Type=unpack("V",substr($Info,($x*8)+16,4));
        if($Type[1]==16) {             //FILEINFO resource
            $InfoFound=TRUE;
            $SubOff=unpack("V",substr($Info,($x*8)+20,4));
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$InfoFound) return FALSE;
    $SubOff[1]&=0x7fffffff;
    $InfoOff=unpack("V",substr($Info,$SubOff[1]+20,4)); //offset of first FILEINFO
    $InfoOff[1]&=0x7fffffff;
    $InfoOff=unpack("V",substr($Info,$InfoOff[1]+20,4));    //offset to data
    $DataOff=unpack("V",substr($Info,$InfoOff[1],4));
    $DataSize=unpack("V",substr($Info,$InfoOff[1]+4,4));
    $CodePage=unpack("V",substr($Info,$InfoOff[1]+8,4));
    $DataOff[1]-=$InfoVirt[1];
    $Version=unpack("v4",substr($Info,$DataOff[1]+48,8));
    $x=$Version[2];
    $Version[2]=$Version[1];
    $Version[1]=$x;
    $x=$Version[4];
    $Version[4]=$Version[3];
    $Version[3]=$x;
    return $Version;
}
```

Não testei esse código, e achei bem ruim de ler, o que não é bom sinal. Mas talvez resolva seu problema.

Talvez o código do usuário Scott Bartgis seja melhor – pelo menos é mais limpo, mas também não testei:

```
<?php
function get_product_version($file_name)
{
   $key = "P\x00r\x00o\x00d\x00u\x00c\x00t\x00V\x00e\x00r\x00s\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00\x00\x00";
   $fptr = fopen($file_name, "rb");
   $data = "";
   while (!feof($fptr))
   {
      $data .= fread($fptr, 65536);
      if (strpos($data, $key)!==FALSE)
         break;
      $data = substr($data, strlen($data)-strlen($key));
   }
   fclose($fptr);
   if (strpos($data, $key)===FALSE)
      return "";
   $pos = strpos($data, $key)+strlen($key);
   $version = "";
   for ($i=$pos; $data[$i]!="\x00"; $i+=2)
      $version .= $data[$i];
   return $version;
}

echo get_product_version("/path_to_file/foo.exe");
?>
```

Uma terceira opção que parece viável: em ambientes Windows, é possível obter a versão de um EXE criando um `FileSystemObject` via extensão COM.

Comment: O return poderia ser `null` pra ficar mais intuitivo que o app não tem marcado a versão via "winver" :) - Só sugestão, entendo que é 3rd e que não há garantias.

Answer (score 2):

Encontrei [esta resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41250734/1518921) que parece muito boa, no entanto **não** posso afirmar que irá funcionar em todos ambientes, de qualquer forma o código retorna bastante coisa:

```
function getFileVersionInfo($filename,$encoding='UTF-8'){
    $dat = file_get_contents($filename);
    if($pos=strpos($dat,mb_convert_encoding('VS_VERSION_INFO','UTF-16LE'))){
        $pos-= 6;
        $six = unpack('v*',substr($dat,$pos,6));
        $dat = substr($dat,$pos,$six[1]);
        if($pos=strpos($dat,mb_convert_encoding('StringFileInfo','UTF-16LE'))){
            $pos+= 54;
            $res = [];
            $six = unpack('v*',substr($dat,$pos,6));
            while($six[2]){
                $nul = strpos($dat,"\0\0\0",$pos+6)+1;
                $key = mb_convert_encoding(substr($dat,$pos+6,$nul-$pos-6),$encoding,'UTF-16LE');
                $val = mb_convert_encoding(substr($dat,ceil(($nul+2)/4)*4,$six[2]*2-2),$encoding,'UTF-16LE');
                $res[$key] = $val;
                $pos+= ceil($six[1]/4)*4;
                $six = unpack('v*',substr($dat,$pos,6));
            }
            return $res;
        }
    }
}
```

Os exemplos:

```
echo "<pre>".print_r( getFileVersionInfo('notepad.exe'), true)."</pre>";
echo "<pre>".print_r( getFileVersionInfo('jre-7u9-windows-x64.exe'), true)."</pre>";
```

Retornam:

**notepad.exe (32-bit):**

```
Array
(
    [CompanyName] => Microsoft Corporation
    [FileDescription] => Notepad
    [FileVersion] => 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)
    [InternalName] => Notepad
    [LegalCopyright] => © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
    [OriginalFilename] => NOTEPAD.EXE
    [ProductName] => Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    [ProductVersion] => 6.1.7600.16385
)
```

**jre-7u9-windows-x64.exe (64-bit):**

```
Array
(
    [CompanyName] => Oracle Corporation
    [FileDescription] => Java(TM) Platform SE binary
    [FileVersion] => 7.0.90.5
    [Full Version] => 1.7.0_09-b05
    [InternalName] => Setup Launcher
    [LegalCopyright] => Copyright © 2012
    [OriginalFilename] => jinstall.exe
    [ProductName] => Java(TM) Platform SE 7 U9
    [ProductVersion] => 7.0.90.5
)
```

Comment: Realmente achei muito bom o seu código, porém preciso verificar o arquivo em um banco, você poderia me explicar como implementar seu código a esta necessidade?

Comment: @Alis depende, verificar um arquivo em um banco é muito ambiguo, eu não faço ideia de como esta o seu banco. Os dados binarios do .exe estão em uma coluna na tabela ou o banco só contém o caminho do .exe? Esta usando o que mysql, oracle, sqlserver, sqlite? E qual api PDO, mysqli? Fora que essa sua pergunta agora meio que invalida as respostas atuais. De qualquer forma vou tentar te ajudar, desde que vc responda o que perguntei acima.